Lying is permitted?
I have heard as a kid that lying to prevent someone from thinking you're not shomer Torah Umitzvos is permitted.
So for example if someone asked you if you Davened yesterday and you really didn't, you are allowed to lie to get out of incriminating yourself.
Is there a source for this?
